# fill formset with django raw sql query

Tags: django, formset

I use Django formset factory and update view don't fill subform with
raw SQL query and return 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'ordered'
error.
object query set fine but raw SQL query return this error.

```
'''python
formset = modelformset_factory(model=GiftVoucherSub,
                               form=GiftVoucherSubForm,
                               extra=0,
                               can_delete=True,
                               min_num=1,
                               validate_min=True,
                               )

formset = formset(request.POST or None,
                  queryset=queryset,
                  # initial=initial,
                  prefix='rlt_giftvoucher',
                  )'''
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: i added the code the queryset come from raw sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by adding extra field to forms.py and views queryset with django object.
passanger name with autocomplete.

```
views
queryset = GiftVoucherSub.objects.filter(main_id=id, is_deleted=False).order_by('id')

forms
class GiftVoucherSubForm(forms.ModelForm):
passanger_id = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
                               required=False,
                               widget=forms.HiddenInput()
                               )
passanger_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                              # 'id': 'form_fatura_cari_isim',
                                              'class': 'formset-field table-condensed clearable',
                                              'required': 'True',
                                              'autocomplete': 'off',
                                              'type': 'search',
                                              'onfocus': 'fn_search_passanger(this.id)',
                                          }
                                      )
                                      )


class Meta:
    model = GiftVoucherSub
    fields = [
              'id',
              'main_request_type',
              'sub_request_type',
              'passanger_id',
              'passanger_name',
              'is_deleted',
              ]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(GiftVoucherSubForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.passanger_id:
        extra_value = BoYolcuListesi.objects.get(usertableid=self.instance.passanger_id)
        self.fields['passanger_name'].initial = extra_value.isim
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_tag = True
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'formset-field table-condensed'})
        self.fields[field].label = ''
```